# Regular expression to retain part of the string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string of following kind

```
{"pid":{"source":"Doc","name":"pid","value":"8180"},
"cid":{"source":"Doc","name":"cid","value":null},
"fid":{"source":"Doc","name":"fid","value":"ME453REN0004"}}
```

I need to get the following string

```
  {"pid":"8180",
   "cid":null,
   "fid":"ME453REN0004"}
```

How can use the regular expression for this?

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't rather JSON parse this using [JSON.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)? It will be a lot less fragile to and ordering change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
"([^"]*)".*:([^{]*)\}(,|\})
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Bc4Jdk/2)

[Sample Code](http://ideone.com/mw33Bp):

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"""([^""]*)"".*:([^{]*)\}(,|\})";
        string input = @"{""pid"":{""source"":""Doc"",""name"":""pid"",""value"":""8180""},
""cid"":{""source"":""Doc"",""name"":""cid"",""value"":null},
""fid"":{""source"":""Doc"",""name"":""fid"",""value"":""ME453REN0004""}}
";
        string result="{";
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
        {

            result+=m.Groups[1].Value+":"+m.Groups[2].Value+m.Groups[3]+"\n";
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better use json parser but here is my two cents if for some reason, you have to use regex for this :

```
"name":("\w+"),"value":("?\w+"?)
```

See the working example on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gJ9VBt/1).

Hope it helps.